# How to update a record on another table based on the values of the record being modified using a trigger

Tags: triggers, sql-update, firebird

I have two simple (only for explain my problem) tables

1. X with columns (among others): IDX,CODE,NUMBER
2. Y with columns (among others): CODE,NUMBER,id_fromX

I want to (after insert or update table X) update table Y using variables from actual record from X.
To do this I try to use trigger (in table X) like below:

```
SET TERM ^^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER XYZFOR X ACTIVE AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0 AS
begin
  if  (new.CODE is distinct old.CODE)  then
  BEGIN
  EXECUTE STATEMENT ('UPDATE Y SET CODE=:old.CODE, id_fromX=:old.IDX WHERE NUMBER=:old.NUMBER');
  END
end ^^
```

but I get error from the server:

```
Execute statement error at jrd8_prepare :\
335544569 : Dynamic SQL Error
335544436 : SQL error code = -104
335544634 : Token unknown - line 1, column 23
335544382 : .
Statement : UPDATE Y SET CODE=:old.CODE, id_fromX=:old.IDX WHERE NUMBER=:old.NUMBER\
Data source : Internal::
At trigger 'XYZ' line: 15, col: 7
```

Static update like this below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER XYZ FOR X ACTIVE AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0 AS
begin
if  (new.CODE is distinct from old.CODE)  then
BEGIN
EXECUTE STATEMENT ('UPDATE Y SET CODE=1, id_fromX=111 WHERE NUMBER=1');
END
end ^^
SET TERM ; ^^
```

works perfect.
How to reference to X table fields to update table Y (fields with similar names)?

Comment: @ain IMHO, the title is still wrong, since the question is not about how to use execute statement, but about how to update a record on other table based on values of the record being modified. (with or without execute statement).

Comment: Hmm, I tought that the OP really wants to use the `execute statement` to do the update (althought it doesn't quite make sense in this simple situation) so that's the main point of the question... anyway, I think the subject I suggested is better than the original, if you think you can come up with even better one then go for it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a colon, but the old/new *records* don't use it.  Also, don't use a execute statement here, since the sql statement is static.

Change it to:

```
SET TERM ^^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER XYZFOR X ACTIVE AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0 AS
begin
  if  (new.CODE is distinct old.CODE)  then
  BEGIN
    UPDATE Y 
       SET CODE = old.CODE, id_fromX = old.IDX 
     WHERE NUMBER = old.NUMBER;
  END
end ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write parameters directly into statement with `EXECUTE STATEMENT`, see [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-with-params) for correct syntax. Basically, it should be something like

```
EXECUTE STATEMENT ('UPDATE Y SET CODE = :CODE, id_fromX = :IDX WHERE NUMBER=:NUMBER')
(CODE := old.CODE, IDX := old.IDX, NUMBER := old.NUMBER);
```

But you actually don't need the `EXECUTE STATEMENT` here, use UPDATE statement "directly".

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the trigger context variables (`old.<column>` and `new.<column>`) in `EXECUTE STATEMENT` as they are separate contexts (the statement in `EXECUTE STATEMENT` can't see them). You either need to use a normal `UPDATE` statement without resorting to `EXECUTE STATEMENT`, or you should pass [parameters](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt-wparams). Like:

```
EXECUTE STATEMENT 
   ('UPDATE Y SET CODE=:code, id_fromX=:idx WHERE NUMBER=:number') 
   (code := old.CODE, idx := old.IDX, number := old.NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't :old.CODE be old.CODE?

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately similar error (unknown column):"Execute statement error at jrd8_prepare :\
335544569 : Dynamic SQL Error
335544436 : SQL error code = -206
335544578 : Column unknown
335544382 : OLD.NUMBER
336397208 : At line 1, column 63
Statement : UPDATE Y SET CODE=old.CODE, id_fromX=old.IDX WHERE NUMBER=old.NUMBER\
Data source : Internal::
At trigger 'XYZ' line: 15, col: 7"